# Using javascripts XMLHttpRequest to open file on localhost for Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple JavaScript function that opens an XML-File. The file URL is simply the one of the website displayed right now, obtained in the JavaScript file of a Firefox extension via

```
var url =content.document.location.href;
```

this works just fine, next,

```
xml=loadXMLDoc(url);
```

should give me this file, which works just fine on websites on the internet. however, I set up a local machine now, and instead of http:publicwebsite.com/file.rdf I now have `http://localhost/file.rdf` and suddenly the JavaScript function loadXMLDoc does not produce any result.

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)

{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

{

    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

}

else

{

    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}
try 
{
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false); // open server interface
} 
catch (err)
{ // if error occurs
    alert("XMLHttpRequest.open() failed.\n"+    err);
}


xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);

xhttp.send("");
alert(xhttp.responseXML);

return xhttp.responseXML;

}
```

the alert(xhttp.responseXML); returns null.

Is this a problem with the same origin policy or what did I miss?

Comment: Why on earth do you have `xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");` in a Firefox extension?!?!

Comment: @Quentin yeah...thats kinda useless. The code sample was cross browser, I should clean that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing an extension - there is no same-origin policy, you are allowed to read whatever you like. I rather suspect that the MIME type returned by your local server is incorrect, it needs to be an XML MIME type to be processed by XMLHttpRequest correctly (probably `application/rdf+xml` in this case). If you are using Apache the following directive in the server config should do:

```
AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf
```

If you cannot influence the server but you are certain that what you get back is an XML file you can also use [overrideMimeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XmlHttpRequest#overrideMimeType%28%29):

```
xhttp.overrideMimeType("application/rdf+xml");
```

Comment: changing the server configuration is not an option for me since the firefox extension is supposed to be able to work with all files it finds on the web independent of the server they are on.
Up till now that did work, just on the localhost it does not.

Comment: @Lukas Ruge: In other words, you want it to work with incorrectly configured servers? I edited my answer even though I find this solution rather questionable.

Comment: Thanks adding the mime type override did the trick... great advice.

Comment: I wuld like the servers to be configured correctly, but at the end it's up to the people who configure it and I would like the extension to be foult tollerant